# Set Local Notification from Selecting Table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, localnotification

Actually This question has been asked so many Times. But I have Confusion Among those. I have tried this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([[cell.btn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]])
    {
        [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UILocalNotification *reminderNote =[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    reminderNote.soundName = @"music.mp3";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];
    reminderNote.alertBody = @"Wish birthday to :%@",[kAppDelegate.commString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *date =[kAppDelegate.String objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDate *dateP = [ dateformat dateFromString:date];
    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:dateP];
        [components setHour:4];
        [components setMinute:59];
        [components setSecond:10];

    reminderNote.fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
    }
```

Where cell is object of `UITableviewCell`, But There is Not any Type of Notification. I know there is a little Bug , please help me to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Place the last line as **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];** after **reminderNote.fireDate** line.
- log the **reminderNote.fireDate** and check the format.

Hope this helps.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if([[cell.btn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]])
        {
            [cell.btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UILocalNotification *reminderNote =[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        reminderNote.soundName = @"music.mp3";
        reminderNote.alertBody = @"Wish birthday to :%@",[kAppDelegate.commString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *date =[kAppDelegate.String objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSDate *dateP = [ dateformat dateFromString:date];
        components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:dateP];
            [components setHour:4];
            [components setMinute:59];
            [components setSecond:10];

        reminderNote.fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the local notifications upto 64 at single time.

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSDate *newDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(6*60*60)];
    // 6*60*60=6 hour*60 minutes*60 seconds
    // [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(6*60*60*i)];
    localNotification.fireDate = newDate;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
    localNotification.alertBody = alertText;
    localNotification.alertAction = alertAction;
    if(soundfileName == nil)
    {
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    }
    else
    {
        localNotification.soundName = soundfileName;
    }
    localNotification.alertLaunchImage = launchImage;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
    //        NSLog(@"%@", [localNotification description]);
    // Schedule it with the app
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

If you want to keep all the objects of `NSNotification`, then you need to store that somewhere. i.e in Array.

You can also use following methods for NSNotifications operation.

`- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
- (void)cancelAllLocalNotifications`

Make sure you are receiving notifications on

`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`

As a good practice prior to use the object, make sure you have initialized and set all the values to particular object.

Answer (score 0):

please try this for local notification

```
-(void)localnotification{

    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datepicker date];

    // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = self.labelname.text;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```